# How to attach multiple file in Laravel 5 Codeception

Tags: input, laravel-5, codeception, multiple-file-upload

I would like to attach several files to run my test in Laravel 5.2 and Codeception 2.1.6.

I have an input :

```
<input type="file" id="shapefiles" name="files[]" multiple>
```

When I try to attach some files to it like this :

```
$I->attachFile('files[]', 'districts/shapefiles/admin2.dbf');
$I->attachFile('files[]', 'districts/shapefiles/admin2.shp');
```

I get the error :

```
[TestRuntimeException] None of form fields by files[] were not matched
```

I can't reproduce the behaviour I would like to test here.
I didn't find any advice on my friend Google. How could I manage to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried changing your locator to xpath or css? I don't think you can use `name` as a locator

Comment: Yes you can use a name as locator, it works when I want to pass only one file. However, I tried to add an id `files` on the input and to target it on the two `attachFile` instruction, like that : `$I->attachFile('#files', 'districts/shapefiles/admin2.dbf');` and it returns exactly the same error message.